# Creating a select option on a dropdown form field

Tags: php, yii2, twig

I am Using Yii2 to develop a web app, my View files are in twig,How do i create a form field with a dropdown list / select options ?

I have the same view file in php and the dropdown is okay, I have tried converting it to twig but i am stuck. I am beginner to twig templates.

view file in php

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    <?php $items = 
     ['minutes'=>'minutes','hours'=>'hours','days'=>'days',]; 
     ?>
     <?= $form->field
       ($model, 'online_time_select')->dropDownList($items, 
       ['prompt' => 'Select']); ?>
     </div>
     </div>
```

View file in twig

```
  <div class="col-sm-6">
       {{ form.field(model, 'online_time_select') | raw }}
  </div>
```

Comment: why symfony tag?

Comment: just a little search on google..[https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/twig-how-use-dropdownlist/80535](https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/twig-how-use-dropdownlist/80535)